# Not sure what to put for strong parameters in nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

I'm trying to debug a controller that just won't play ball. I've narrowed it down to the strong parameters not working properly and so I've tried it out on the rails console.

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  "user"=> {
    "login"=>"username",
    "password"=>"[FILTERED]"
   },
  "staff_id"=>"1"
})
```

This returns, as you'd expect:

```
=> {"user"=>{"login"=>"username", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "staff_id"=>"1"}
```

So, I attempted to filter the parameters, like so...

```
params.require(:staff_id)
=> "1" 

> params.require(:user).permit(:password,:login)
=> {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"username"}
```

That looks ok.

In my controller, I have:

```
def create    
  @staff=Staff.find(params[:staff_id])
  @user = @staff.create_user(reg_params[:user])
  DISASTER
```

Now, at the point of the disaster, the user object @user should have a login and password set but It doesn't. I've tried logging the @user object at that point, it's properties are nil.

Why isn't my user object being created properly? If I remove the DISASTER, it creates a database record with blank fields, except for the timestamps.

Models:

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :staff
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150909102012) do
  create_table "staff", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "qualifications"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "staff", ["users_id"], name: "index_staff_on_users_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "login"
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "password"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

It routes to the custom controller ok. Here's the route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
  resources :staff do
    resource :user, shallow: true, controller: 'staff_register'
  end

  resources :users
```

There's nothing else in the app because it's just an experiment to help me work on a bigger problem I've been struggling with.

Basically, I want to be able to link a staff model to a user model. I think I've done that ok, I just need help figuring out the strong parameters bit.

EDIT: here's the form for the nested resource:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => staff_user_path(@staff) do |f| %>    
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>   
    <div id="error_explanation">    
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">    
    <%= f.label :login %><br>    
    <%= f.text_field :login %>    
  </div>  

  <div class="field">    
    <%= f.label :password %><br>    
    <%= f.text_field :password %>    
  </div>

  <div class="actions">    
    <%= f.submit %>    
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: A good start is to add validations to your user model. Verify the presence of the attributes login and password. Its easier than to check the record on the database everytime.

Comment: What's `reg_params`?

Comment: reg_params is my filtered list of params.

Comment: Assuming `reg_params` is a method containing `require(:user)`, you shouldn't have `reg_params[:user]`, but simply `reg_params`. Otherwise you are passing `nil` to a `create` method

Comment: @BroiSatse is that right? Note that it's a nested resource though, so I need staff_id in there too.

Comment: That means your form is incorrect, as `staff_id` should be within `user` hash. Could you post the form view?

Comment: @BroiSatse sure, added above.

Comment: Ah, now i see. Sorry, form was not necessary. I'll post an answer in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
@user = @staff.create_user(reg_params[:user])
```

`reg_params` already gives you hash with all the permitted parameters:

```
{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"username"}
```

There is no `user` key there, hence `reg_params[:user]` is just `nil`. Instead you need to do:

```
@user = @staff.create_user(reg_params)
```

Now, you do not need to worry about `staff_id` here, as you are executing `create_user` method on already existing `@staff` model. This method will take care of the association.